# I am unable to convert my SID to a friendly name using PowerShell on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

> $RootPath = "K:\FolderName"
>
> $Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
>
> foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {   $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname |
>   ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }     Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
>       {
>
> ```
>     $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($ACL.IdentityReference) 
>     // the above line gives an error
>     $objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 
>     $objUser.Value
>
>     $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $objUser.Value  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," +
> ```
>
> $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
>           Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile    } }

The error is

```
+     $objSID = New-Object <<<<  System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($
ACL.IdentityReference) 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvoca 
   tionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power 
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "The trust relationship bet
ween this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

Comment: Is your worstation joined to the same domain as the computer that the you're getting those ACLs from?

Comment: All computers are on the same domain.